# Eclipse -- SharedClasses has build path errors

Tags: java, eclipse, build, compiler-errors, eclipse-indigo

Please bear with me, since I am not a java Developer, and all of this is extrememly new for me.

I am running Eclipse Indigo, and have a Project that I need ot build and compile .class files form the existing .java files.  I have designated an output location in my directory.  Within the Properties panel for the Project, for my Java Build Path, I correctly linked all the JARs and none of them are listed as missing or unbound.

After attempting to Clean and Build, I am left with no results.  The Error Log shows that:

> Failed to retrieve default libraries for
>   ../JavaLibrary/jre/jdk1.6.0_20

And the Problem Log shows that:

> The Project was not built since it depends on SharedClasses, which has
>   build path errors

As I stated before, I was under the assumption that my Java Build Path was correct, but I cannot locate these errors.  As for the Java Development Kit 1.6, It is linked properly in the Java Build Path, so I am at a complete loss.

Can anyone direct me to how I can correct this issue that I am having?

Answer (score 1):

Check errors in project libs,

right click to project --> Preferences --> Java Build Path -- Libraries